# How to select columns from single table when using a belongsToMany relationship in Laravel 4 Eloquent model?

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-4, many-to-many, eloquent

What Laravel 4 Eloquent code will generate this exact query given an Account and Project model? Note Im only selecting the columns from the project table.

```
select `project`.* from `project` inner join `account_project` on `project`.`id` = `account_project`.`project_id` where `account_project`.`account_id` = 'AAA' and `project`.`id` = 'BBB' limit 1
```

The closest Ive found so far is the code below. This issue is that it also returns the columns for the pivot table (account_project). I'm return this model as JSON and do not want the pivot columns included in the JSON.

```
$project = Account::find($account->id)->projects()->where('id', $projectId)->first();
```

Here is the query (non-Eloquent) that generates the exact query:

```
Project::query()->join('account_project', 'project.id', '=', 'account_project.project_id')->where('project.id', $projectId)->where('account_project.account_id', $account->id)->select('project.*')->first();
```

Comment: Is eager loading not an option?  foreach(Account::with('Project')->get() as $account){ /* $account->name, $account->project->id */ }

Comment: Otherwise, you'll have to use query builder to get the exact query result you're looking for.  You can't join two Eloquent models together.

Comment: Ok. I see you've answered your own question.

Comment: No I havent' The question is for how to generate that query using Eloquent models, not direct queries.

Comment: An eloquent model will not generate that query because the two eloquent models have a relationship.  What you're describing in the query is a copy of account information for each project. Account model properties and methods can't merge or override Project's properties and methods... which is why I suggested the eager loading.  It's a different query, but I think it's what you're trying to achieve.  You iterate over the Accounts and have access to it's related Projects (and vice versa), but they're maintained as separate models through a relation.

Comment: Use `hidden` property on the model or even better transformers in order to control what you return in JSON response.